# Vba row count with first letter

Tags: excel, counter, vba

I want to create a text file row counter, but if I merge the texts from all columns into one cell in every rows, will be more thousends char in a cell and it goes error. I try to split this merged strings to take the first char only into the first cells in every rows, but it doesn't work. How can I fixed it? Or how can I count the first column only?

```
Sub counter()

    Dim GoToNum As Integer
    Dim Start As Integer
    GoToNum = 2
    Start = 3

    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(Start, 1))
        GoToNum = GoToNum + 1
        Start = Start + 1
    Loop

    Dim SubCounter As Integer
    Dim curLine As String

    For i = 3 To GoToNum

            ConOrg = Cells(1, 4).Value & "\" & Cells(i, 1).Value

            'If Cells(i, 2).Value <= Cells(2, 5).Value Then

                Open ConOrg For Input As #1

                Do Until EOF(1)
                    SubCounter = SubCounter + 1
                    Line Input #1, Left(curLine, 1)
                    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(SubCounter, 3).Value = curLine
                Loop

                Cells(i, 3).Value = SubCounter
                SubCounter = 0

                Close #1

            'End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give an example (with screenshot) what you are trying to do?

Comment: In several text files include 30 or more columns, that's why if I use the Line Input # the char number of the string (what create the Line Input #) will reach the char limit what can include one cell.

Comment: A screenshot would be quite better :)

Comment: I work with sensitive data.